# Visual Studio 2015 Preview CTP6 - angular-ui-grid

Tags: visual-studio-2015, angular-ui-grid

I have a problem with adding reference to **angular-ui-grid** on **Visual Studio 2015 Preview CTP6**. It directly blocks VS and close itself also removes .sln file and makes it imposible to open the same solution. I know it is preview version, but is there anoyone else facing this problem or else only me?

Comment: How are you adding it? I don't think there's a nuget package for ui-grid yet. At least not a correct/current one.

Comment: VS 2015 supports bower, so I am simply adding into bower.json file at the root directory of project. Other bower packages so far are working but there is specifically something wrong with this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've done a workaround which crippled the Bower reference tree in Visual Strudio. I've added into bower.json file but I closed VS before doing that to prevent any runtime error and executed bower install command on that file. When I open the VS, Bower reference section in the Solution Explorer was gone, it was not showing any references for Bower but NPM references was still there. At least I can keep developing things again.